# DataGridView – Strings & Decimals in the same Column/Cell

Tags: c#, string, datagridview, decimal

I’m looking for suggestions.

I have a bound DataGridView with a nullable decimal column, and was just informed that it also needs to take ‘N/A’ as an input/output. My thought right now is to hide the bound column and display an input column that lets you input either decimal or ‘N/A’, and upon validation of the cell write the data to the hidden bound column using a -1.0 for “N/A”. When I load the grid, I would loop through the ‘hidden’ column and ‘copy/translate’ the data to the visible column. The worst case scenario is approx. 200 rows of which 50/60 max are visible.
This project is still in Dev/Test, so changing the column in the DB isn’t the worst thing to happen.

If there is a better way, I’m listening.

Thanks.

Comment: I have to ask, if you want to allow the user to type “N/A”… then… are you also wanting the user to be allowed to type “other” text also, like “hello”?

Comment: No. Just "N/A" if not a decimal. I"m allowing variants of N/A: na, n/a, NA, N/A that all display as "N/A" and are saving as -1.0. If you type anything else, you get an error flag/icon that doesn't let you save.

Comment: Then you will have to “capture” the user keystrokes as they type them into the cell. Obviously, the column will have to be a “text” column, which will allow the user to type any character. It is not that difficult “capture” only numeric values and a single decimal point. However, when you also want to allow the user to type those characters, you may end up with “123N23” or “456A/N” or "AAA” or “///” etc. This is doable, but it is not trivial.

Comment: A simple solution that allows only numeric values and a single decimal point sounds like a better approach. AND if the cell is left empty and the user “leaves” the cell, then the cell will display “N/A” and set -1 to the hidden column. The difference is that the user will NOT be able to “type” in “N/A”. To get “N/A”, simply remove the text in the cell and then leave the cell. The code will add the “N/A.”

Comment: I used the CellValidating() event to check for the 'n/a' inputs or valid decimal. I'm also checking for null/blank as they may not want to enter data yet. I do have it working using the CellValidating() & CellValidated() events and copying the data as I stated in the original post. I was posting for better ideas. I don't capture keystrokes, but check after typing is finished.

Comment: Then the user can type "anything" into the cell and the cell validating with catch incorrect values. If this works for you then I do not see what the issue is. Just have cell validating allow "N/A." I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: John G - You aren't missing anything. I posted looking for suggestions that might be better that where I was going. I was wanting to make sure I wasn't missing the forest for the trees.

Comment: I am glad you have a solution. I would just say in the future, it will help others and you if you make it clear what you want. Example, in my first comment, I asked if the user is allowed to type “hello”… you said No, just “N/A” or variations. This is technically not true and your answer confirms this. The user IS allowed to type “hello” and any other characters they choose. When you said “No”… then I felt it was necessary to “capture” the keystrokes. It helps to make it clear what you want. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The following events are how I solved the problem

```
   private void grvRegrindRolls_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
   {
      if (StatusMode == FormStatusMode.Initialized && blnShown)
      {
         if (e.RowIndex >= 0)  //Not a new row
         {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index)
            {
               if (grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value != null
                  && ((string)grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper() != "N/A")
                  && ((string)grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper() != "NA")
                  && !IsValidDecimal((grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value), false))
               {
                  grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].ErrorText = INVALID;
               }
               else
                  grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].ErrorText = NO_ERROR;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private void grvRegrindRolls_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
      if (StatusMode == FormStatusMode.Initialized && blnShown)
      {
         if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index)  //Not a new row
         {
            if (grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value != null
               && ((string)grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper() != "N/A")
               && ((string)grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper() != "NA")
               && !IsValidDecimal((grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value), false))
            {
               grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].ErrorText = INVALID;
            }
            else
            {
               if (grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value != null
                  && IsValidDecimal(grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value, false))
               {
                  grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmount.Index, e.RowIndex].Value = grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value;
               }
               else if (grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value != null
                  && ((grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper() == "N/A")
                  || (grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper() == "NA")))
               {
                  grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmount.Index, e.RowIndex].Value = "-1.000";
               }
               else if (grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value == null || grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Trim() == "")
               {
                  grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmount.Index, e.RowIndex].Value = null;
               }

               grvRegrindRolls[grcRRCenterAmountIn.Index, e.RowIndex].ErrorText = NO_ERROR;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private void grvRegrindRolls_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
   {
      //Uncancel the cell to allow the user to leave it
      e.Cancel = false;
   }
```